# Synapse / Data Factory: Do Self Hosted Integration Runtimes expose data locally

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, data-security

We need to ensure that the VM hosting the Self Hosted Integration Runtime (SHIR) can be supported without risking exposure of the data being processed by the SHIR - which may be sensitive in nature.

What information related to data sources is cached locally on the VM hosting a Self Hosted Integration Runtime (SHIR)? For example, if SHIR is pulling data from an on-prem SQL Server, is it possible that data queried could be exposed in error / event logs on the VM?

Thanks.

- Matt

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this is not a risk

> Azure Data Factory including Azure Integration Runtime and Self-hosted Integration Runtime does not store any temporary data, cache data or logs except for linked service credentials for cloud data stores, which are encrypted by using certificates.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-movement-security-considerations